# Usar drop ou iloc na modelagem para Machine Learning no Pandas?

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, pandas, machine-learning

Estou aprendendo Machine Learning para Data Science através do Pandas. Fiz alguns poucos algoritmos e realizava a divisao das minhas variáveis previsoras e classe da seguinte forma:

```
dados = pd.read_csv(...)
(...)
previsores = dados.drop('income', axis=1)
classe = dados['income']
```

Porém, comecei a percerber algumas pessoas usando o iloc, por exemplo:

```
dados = pd.read_csv(...)
(...)
previsores = dados.iloc[:,0:14].values
classe = dados.iloc[:,14].values
```

Eu estava achando que ambos poderiam estar corretos, mas percebi que o type do primeiro era um DF do Pandas e o do segundo um numpy.array.

Alguém poderia me esclarecer se a forma como eu estava fazendo antes era errada, e quais as implicações de fazer de uma ou de outra forma?

Comment: André, bom dia! Não é questão de errado ou certo. Alguns algoritmos pedem um numpy array, outros você pode entregar como um data frame mesmo. No seu exemplo, caso você faça `dados['income'].values` também terá o array do numpy, independentemente de utilizar o `loc`ou `iloc`. Com iloc ou slicing geralmente você não precisa se preocupar com o nome das colunas.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado. No meu caso aqui eu tenho que usar o OneHotEncoder, portanto necessito de Arrays!

Answer (score 0):

O que acontece é o seguinte, o `iloc` recebe dois parâmetros, linhas e columnas: `iloc[linhas,colunas]`. Linhas pode ser uma única linha ou mais de uma (o mesmo vale pra coluna). Se for apenas uma você simplesmente diz qual o número da linha, se for mais de uma você pode usar uma lista ou um intervalo, que no python se representa com `:`.

Como funciona esse intervalo: `começo:fim:passo` representa um intervalo que se inicia em `começo` termina antes de `fim` pulando de passo em passo, por exemplo `1:10:2` vai usar os números de 1 até 10, sem incluir o 10, pulando de 2 em 2, ou seja: `1,3,5,7,9`. Quando você não define o passo, o python intende que ele é 1. Então `0:5` seria `0,1,2,3,4`. O passo também pode ser negativo `4:1:-1` seria `4,3,2`. quando você não define o começo, o python intende que o começo é 0. Portanto `0:14` é a mesma coisa que `:14`. Por último, se você não define o fim, o python entende que ele deve pegar o intervalo inteiro.

No caso do seu código nós temos dois intervalos sendo usados no `iloc`. O primeiro é `dados.iloc[:,0:14]` onde está sendo informado que para a coluna o intervalo é `:`, ou seja, nem o começo, nem o fim e nem o passo estão sendo definidos, o que significa que o python ira utilizar todas as linhas, da linha 0 até a última, inclusive. Para a coluna `0:14` indica que serão todas as colunas da coluna 0 até a coluna 14, sem incluir a coluna 14 (de 0 a 13). Então você tem várias linhas e 14 colunas. Ou seja, uma matriz de 2 dimensões. No segundo caso você tem iloc[:,14], que significa mais uma vez todas as linhas, mas apenas da coluna 14. Ou seja, você tem apenas uma dimensão.

Para o pandas, `dados.iloc[:,14]` seria ainda um DataFrame com uma única coluna, mas `.values` pede pro pandas te retornar os valores desse DataFrame e, segundo a definição do pandas, se esse DataFrame tem uma única dimensão, ele te retorna um array de numpy.

Comment: Muito boa a explicação, essa questão dos intervalos eu já estava entendendo, mas mesmo assim o seu comentário foi bem esclarecedor.
Minha dúvida era mais mesmo relacionada a qual seria a diferença em relação aos tipos e como isso influenciava no código, mas como responderam acima, para determinadas situações é melhor manter como DF (copiando e apenas dropando as colunas inuteis) e em outros casos é melhor array.

No meu caso, estou usando o OneHotEncoder, que necessita de arrays, portanto o meu método anterior estaria 'errado'.

Valeu pela explicação, vou até salvar o comentário kkkkk

Comment: Obrigado. Se você achou que ajudou peço, por favor, que marque como útil.

Comment: Marquei!! valeu aí

Comment: pra marcar como útil você precisa clicar uma vez na setinha para cima à esquerda da pergunta.